# Sorting objects by date in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting, datetime, activerecord

I have an array of tracking event objects with a datetime field stored on them. I need to sort the array by the datetime field however when I use the code `tracking_events.sort { |te| te.datetime }` There is no sorting on the array.

I cannot use `.order(:datetime)` as the array of tracking events is created by adding the tracking events of two different models so it has a standard Array type instead of an active record association. I know that I could use a `.where(id: ids)` in order to use the `.order` method but this does not seem like the correct solution. Does anyone have any idea on why the `.sort` is not working?

I have also tried to convert the DateTime fields to integers which did not help either.

Comment: [`sort`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#sort-method) passes _two_ elements into the block which is expected to calculate the comparison result, e.g. `sort { |a, b| a.datetime <=> b.datetime }`. You probably want [`sort_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Enumerable.html#sort_by-method) which just has to return a (sortable) value from the block. (as in your example)

Comment: This was the right solution, thank you so much.